# Access all variables inside parent slider in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created this slider which is parent component and there are multiple child components

> Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcgxgh?file=src/app/slide2/slide2.component.html
>
> Slider In parent component :

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let ques of current_slide_lists; let i = index">
    <div class="mySlides animated fadeInRight">
      <app-slide1 *ngIf="ques == 'Multiple choice'"> </app-slide1>
      <app-slide2 *ngIf="ques == 'Single choice'"> </app-slide2>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

> Child Component 1:

```
<p>
  Multiple choice Questions :
  <br />
  <input
    #optA
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    name="answer"
    id="answer_A"
    value="A"
  />
  Option 1
  <br />
  <input
    #optB
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    name="answer"
    id="answer_A"
    value="A"
  />
  Option 2
  <br />
  <input
    #optC
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    name="answer"
    id="answer_A"
    value="A"
  />
  Option 3
</p>
```

> Child Component 2:

```
Single choice choice Option :
<br />
<input
  [(ngModel)]="select_option"
  type="radio"
  name="answer"
  id="answer_A"
  value="A"
/>Option 1
<br />
<input
  [(ngModel)]="select_option"
  type="radio"
  name="answer"
  id="answer_A"
  value="B"
/>Option 2
<br />
<input
  [(ngModel)]="select_option"
  type="radio"
  name="answer"
  id="answer_A"
  value="C"
/>Option 3
```

There will be multiple child components, these two child components are for example purpose like there may be child component where user enters in textboxes and select the dropdown. I don't have much knowledge in Angular i was trying like if user clicks on results button which is on parent component, all the variables of child component can be accessed by parent also because result function will be on parent component. Is there any way i can pass all the data to child component and those data (Variables) if manipulated by child component can be accessed by parent also like in the above example if i select some checkbox that selected option value should be accessible in parent component also. There will be only single Parent Component.

Any solution is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to comunicate child with parent you use an [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event). Remember that can emit what-you-want

In children

```
@Output() dataChange= new EventEmitter<any>();

//you can use, e.g.
  this.dataChange.emit({data:'hello',value:'other',count:0);
```

In parent

```
<app-slide1 (dataChange)="makeSomething($event)"...>
makeSomething(data:any)
{
   console.log(data)
}
```

You can also from parent get the children using a template reference variable and [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

```
  <app-slide1 #slide *ngIf="ques == 'Multiple choice'"> </app-slide1>
  <app-slide2 #slide *ngIf="ques == 'Single choice'"> </app-slide2>

  ViewChildren('slide') slides:QueryList<any>

  //and,e.g.
  const value=slides.first.anyVariable
```

But in this case you can **not** use `*ngIf` else

```
[style.display]="!condition?'none':null"
```

The last is pass a complex object in an input

In parent

```
  obj:any={};

  <app-slide1 [dataObject]="obj" ...> </app-slide1>
  <app-slide2 [dataObject]="obj" ...> </app-slide2>
```

In child

```
@Input() dataObject;
//in any place
this.dataObject.newProperty="Hello"

//but be carefull, it's NOT allowed
//this.dataObject=...
```

**Update**

A particular case is when our childs are forms.

First we need choose if we want to use ReactiveForms (FormGroups) or Template driven form (using [(ngModel)])

In both cases the simplex is pass a FormGroup or an object as input.

Example using FromGroup

```
//in parent
form=new FormGroup({
    property:new FormControl()
})
<app-slide1 [control]="form.get('property')"...></app-slide1>

//in child
control:FormControl
@Input('control') _control(value)
{
    this.control=value as FormControl
}
<input [formControl]="control">
```

Example using ngModel

```
//in parent
obj={property:null}

<!--see that you pass the whole object-->
<app-slide1 [data]="obj" field="property" ...></app-slide1>

//in child
@Input() data
@Input() field
<input [(ngModel)]="data[field]">
```

See that in both you pass an Object so you has an unique object -a change in child has the result that the object change -so in parent is showed the change-

In ReactiveForms we use a "setter" to "cast" the control because `form.get('property')` is an AbstractControl -well we know that is a FormControl but typescript not and give us an error.

When we want to use ngModel (and we want mannage an unique property of one object), we can use a [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding)

In children

```
//in child
@Input() data
@Output() dataChange=new EventEmitter<any>()
<input [ngModel]="data" (ngModelChange)="dataChange.emit($event)">
```

So in parent we can use some like

```
<app-slide1 [(data)]="obj.property" ...></app-slide1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have one more doubt can you please clear it, suppose there can be radio buttons, checkboxes or textfield in the child component and result button is on parent component so i have to use onchange event on radio button checkboxes and textfields, then updated selected value of each control is transferred to the parent component when user clicks on the button which is inside parent component, Is this correct way

Comment: @user3653474, I update the answer in the particular case to mannage forms. There're also another approaches not in answer. There're no one better than others, only different approaches